# xcode iOS remove splash screen when app invoked by another app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, splash-screen

I have an app that is using facebook login. When I press the facebook login button it takes me to the facebook app, when everything is authorised and transition from facebook app to my app starts, my app shows a splash screen for a few miliseconds.

My question is: Is it possible to remove the splash screen in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think it is even possible to remove the splash however it is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, iOS does not allow to change or remove the app's splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this Entry (key,value) from your project's info.plist.
 [image]

Comment: This will still show the splash screen, in your case a black one (after removing LaunchScreen).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the "Launch Screen file" under your target settings on the General tab, Check this link:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/